# voujs- background animation fade in and out base of data

Tags: css, vuejs2

I have a div that voudjs control its backgound.
I want to add some animation to the backgound so it will be fade out to transparent right after. Like a blink.  or maybe fast fade in out.
possible?
https://jsfiddle.net/za3gutw4/

```
<div id="app">
  <p :style="{ 'background-color': (diff) ? 'red' : 'transparent' }">{{rand}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't find a way to animate the background color, you might try putting another layer in behind your paragraph to act as your fading background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can add `transition` property for you paragraph that you want to be animated in your CSS code:

```
p {
  transition: background-color .3s;
}
```

Having that class styling is easy. You have to add `transition` property with the value you need to base element:

```
p {
  transition: background .3s;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      rand: 0,
      diff: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      this.diff = rand !== this.rand;
      this.rand = rand;
    }, 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  transition: background .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p :style="{ 'background-color': (diff) ? 'red' : 'transparent' }">{{rand}}</p>
</div>
```